# Find and divide all numbers in a file using sed

Tags: macos, sed

I am trying to find all numbers in a json file and replace them with a half value of the original number using sed on mac. For example, here I search for 2010 and replace it with 1005:

```
file="data.json"
sed -i '' -E 's,([^0-9]|^)2010([^0-9]|$),\1 1005\2,g' "$file"
```

I would like to find all number instances, and replace them with half values of themselves. It would need to work on decimals, eg: 2009 would become 1004.5, 10.5 would become 5.25.

I'm aware this could take each individual number character, so perhaps it would need to find numbers with non-numerical characters either side of it.

edit: I would like it to be flexible and work on all forms of text files, not just JSON files. (.txt, .html, .rtf etc...)

Comment: Why parse JSON with `sed`? Download and install `jq` - A syntax aware parser for JSON

Comment: Provide a JSON sample snippet for us to show how you could this with `jq`

Comment: I would like it to be flexible to work on all forms of text files, not just JSON. I will update my question

Comment: Or use Perl: `perl -pe 's{(?<!\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\d)}{$1/2}ge' file`

Comment: GNU sed has `s///e` for shelling out, but as it pulls the entire line into the pattern buffer, it's hard to use to parse out numbers without losing the surrounding context. ie `printf '5\n6.5\n' | sed "s%.*%echo 'scale=3;&/2.0' | bc%e"` .... gets the numbers divided by 2 with `bc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use Perl with a regex with `e` modifier:

```
perl -pe 's{(?<!\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\d)}{$1/2}ge' file
```

To modify the file inline, add `-i` option:

```
perl -i -pe 's{(?<!\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\d)}{$1/2}ge' file
perl -pi.bak -e 's{(?<!\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\d)}{$1/2}ge' file # To save a backup of the original file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/0Hd6DG):

```
s="abc_2010_and+2009+or-10.5"
perl -pe 's{(?<!\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\d)}{$1/2}ge' <<< "$s"
# => abc_1005_and+1004.5+or-5.25
```

The `(?<!\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\d)` regex matches

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit immediately to the left is allowed
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1 (`$1`): 1+ digits followed with an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?!\d)` -  no digit immediately to the right is allowed.

The RHS - `$1/2` - is an expression that divides the Group 1 value with `2`. It  is achieved through adding `e` modifier at the end of the regex.

Comment: That outputs perfectly in Terminal using `perl -pe 's{(?<!\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\d)}{$1/2}ge' "$file"`however it does not modify the file. How would I overwrite it in Perl?

Comment: @friendlygiraffe `perl -i -pe 's{(?<!\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\d)}{$1/2}ge' file`. Or, use `perl -pi.bak -e 's{(?<!\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\d)}{$1/2}ge' file` to save a  backup file.

Comment: How to round the output with 2 digits after the dot? using the same above Perl statement, it's working as expected but need to round results

Comment: @mshafey `perl -i -pe 's{(?<!\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\d)}{sprintf("%.2f", $1/2)}ge' file`

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT it'd just be:

```
awk -v RS='[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?' -v ORS= 'RT{$0=$0 RT/2} 1'
```

e.g borrowing @Wiktors example:

```
$ s="abc_2010_and+2009+or-10.5"
$ awk -v RS='[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?' -v ORS= 'RT{$0=$0 RT/2} 1' <<< "$s"
abc_1005_and+1004.5+or-5.25
```

If you want to overwrite an input file then add `-i inplace`:

```
awk -i inplace -v RS...1' file
```